# Append only new aggregates based on groupby keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have to process some files which arrive to me daily. The information have primary key `(date,client_id,operation_id)`. So I created a Stream which append only new data into a delta table:

```py
operations\
        .repartition('date')\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('append')\
        .trigger(once=True)\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/sandbox/operations/_chk")\
        .format('delta')\
        .partitionBy('date')\
        .start('/mnt/sandbox/operations')
```

This is working fine, but i need to summarize this information grouped by `(date,client_id)`, so i created another streaming from this operations table to a new table:

```py
summarized= spark.readStream.format('delta').load('/mnt/sandbox/operations')

summarized= summarized.groupBy('client_id','date').agg(<a lot of aggs>)

summarized.repartition('date')\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('complete')\
        .trigger(once=True)\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/sandbox/summarized/_chk")\
        .format('delta')\
        .partitionBy('date')\
        .start('/mnt/sandbox/summarized')
```

This is working, but every time I got new data into `operations` table, spark recalculates `summarized` all over again. I tried to use the append mode on the second streaming, but it need watermarks, and the date is DateType.

There is a way to only calculate new aggregates based on the group keys and append them on the `summarized`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Spark Structured Streaming - Window Operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time)

When you use windowed operations, it will do the bucketing according to `windowDuration` and `slideDuration`. `windowDuration` tells you what is the length of the window, and `slideDuration` tells by how much time should you slide the window.

If you groupby using [window() [docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window), you will get a resultant `window` column along with other columns you groupby with like `client_id`

For example:

```
windowDuration = "10 minutes"
slideDuration = "5 minutes"
summarized = before_summary.groupBy(before_summary.client_id,
    window(before_summary.date, windowDuration, slideDuration)
).agg(<a lot of aggs>).orderBy('window')
```

Comment: can I use a Date to specify the window?

Comment: @LeandroHumb you will have to specify in ‘days’ or so

Comment: I hope your `date` column is a `timestamp` type

Comment: it is not, date is DateType.

Comment: Please try the `window` operation, if it doesn't work, convert the column to `timestamp` and try difference `windowDuration` and `slideDuration`, and let me know if there are any issues

Comment: tried to convert the field `date` to timestamp, and now the stream process works, but it don't write anything on the sink

Comment: i will just make it batch, can't struggle with this anymore, but thank you @pissall for your attention

Comment: @LeandroHumb if your question found a relevant answer, please upvote and select it. If you need help with writing it to the sink, please update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: nice ideia, I will write another one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135188/streaming-aggregate-not-writing-into-sink