# streaming aggregate not writing into sink

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have to process some files which arrive to me daily. The information have primary key (date,client_id,operation_id). So I created a Stream which append only new data into a delta table:

```
operations\
        .repartition('date')\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('append')\
        .trigger(once=True)\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/sandbox/operations/_chk")\
        .format('delta')\
        .partitionBy('date')\
        .start('/mnt/sandbox/operations')
```

This is working fine, but i need to summarize this information grouped by (date,client_id), so i created another streaming from this operations table to a new table. So i tried to convert my `date` field to a timestamp, so i could use append mode while writing an aggregated stream:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

summarized= spark.readStream.format('delta').load('/mnt/sandbox/operations')
summarized= summarized.withColumn('timestamp_date',F.to_timestamp('date'))
summarized= summarized.withWatermark('timestamp_date','1 second').groupBy('client_id','date','timestamp_date').agg(<lot of aggs>)

summarized\
        .repartition('date')\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('append')\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/sandbox/summarized/_chk")\
        .trigger(once=True)\
        .format('delta')\
        .partitionBy('date')\
        .start('/mnt/sandbox/summarized')
```

This code runs, but it does not write anything in the sink.

why it isn't writing results into sink?

Comment: What is the frequency of data? How many rows would exist every `1 second` of your `timestamp_date` column?

Comment: the data is daily, since `timestamp_date` was converted from `date` I think all rows will be in the same second

Comment: That's incorrect. I don't think you understood very well how to use the `window` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append only new aggregates based on groupby keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100079/append-only-new-aggregates-based-on-groupby-keys)

Comment: It doesn't write to the sink because `summarized` is empty. You are essentially saying, `groupby` every second and perform aggregations. Whereas you might want to groupby a day or something

Comment: not empty, if i do a `display(summarized)` on databricks, or write using the `outputMode('complete')`, it return rows. For me, something is happening on `StateStore`, so it drop all the records before writing on the sink, or there is some bug with writing an aggregate stream using `trigger(once=True)`

Comment: My guess would be that `F.to_timestamp('date')` gives `null` due to malformed input and hence `withWatermark('timestamp_date','1 second')` can never be "materialized". Could you `spark.read.format('delta').load('/mnt/sandbox/operations')` (`read` not `readStream`) and see if the conversion gives proper values?

Answer (score 1):

There could be two issues at play here.

### Malformed Date Input

I'm quite sure that the issue is with `F.to_timestamp('date')` that gives `null` due to malformed input.

If so, `withWatermark('timestamp_date','1 second')` can never be "materialized" and triggers no output.

Could you `spark.read.format('delta').load('/mnt/sandbox/operations')` (to `read` not to `readStream`) and see if the conversion gives proper values?

```
spark.\
  read.\ 
  format('delta').\
  load('/mnt/sandbox/operations').\
  withColumn('timestamp_date',F.to_timestamp('date')).\
  show
```

### All Rows Use Same Timestamp

It is also possible that `withWatermark('timestamp_date','1 second')` does not finishes (and so "completes" an aggregation) because all rows are from the same timestamp so the time does not advance.

You should have rows with different timestamps so the notion of time per the timestamp_date can get past the `'1 second'` lateness window.